# Replacing part of a formula using Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

So I usually use template formulas (like - `=IMPORTRANGE(LINK,Sheet1!A1)` where link is the variable I replace using find and replace).

So, now I wanted to automate this task, i.e. for example the formula sits in cell A1 and the link in B1. Normally, I just go find-> Match in formula also-> Replace. But now I wish to do this using a script that I would connect to a drawing on my sheet.

Recently, upon researching the web(and this SE too), I didn't find any script for replacing something from a formula, which is troublesome for me knowing that I don't know JavaScript to program something myself..

So, can anyone please help me in accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the link in a cell, perhaps in a 'Config' sheet. The same applies to the range reference. Your formula will look like this:

`=importrange(Config!B2, Config!B3)`

To change the link, simply put a new value in cell `Config!B2`. If you want to automate that, use something like this:

`ss.getRange('Config!B2').setValue(newLink);`

To answer your question, you can modify a spreadsheet formula with something like this:

`cell.setFormula(cell.getFormula().replace('2020', '2021'));`

Comment: Such a simple and elegant solution.....thanks a ton..

Comment: P.s. I am really intrigued at how when someone fixes their mind on something, assuming it to be the solution...they become oblivious to all other possible solutions....it is like @doubleunary turned the light inside out for me...an aha moment for me....I am srsly grateful for this lesson in computing as well as mindset...thanks again